# What is the current page's Taxonomy?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, menus, pages

I need to be able to switch between the current page taxonomy so I can load in the appropriate menu:

```
$current_tax = 'need to get this from somewhere';
switch ($current_tax) {
    case 'tax1':
        // load menu1
    break;
    case 'tax3':
        // load menu2
    default:
    break;
}
```

I'm not sure which method is best to get the current page's taxonomy.

Comment: What do you mean under taxonomy? tag, category or custom taxonomy? Read [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies) to define more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace tax_name with the desired taxonomie

```
$tax = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'tax_name');
echo $tax[0]->slug;
```

Comment: $the_terms = get_the_terms($postid, 'custom_taxonomy' );